# Read image files using filestream in ASP.NET and store in Sql server database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

There are around 1k records in my database which have a demographic info + an image column. All the images currently reside in a filesystem and I have been assigned with the task of picking up those images and storing it in the database.

My objective is
1. Using ASP.NET, read an image file from a filesystem
2. Store the image in SQL Server 2008 database

By far I have seen this possible only using FileUpload methods which will be very tedious.

Any help, greatly appreciated

Thanks,
neil

Comment: Doesn't Microsoft provide an ADO-compatible mechanism for creating a stream to SQL? (e.g. for reading/writing TEXT or BLOB columns).

Comment: e.g. See [SqlFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx). I believe it requires 2008. Not sure if it needs R2.

Comment: May be relevant: http://www.aghausman.net/dotnet/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973829/sql-server-filestream-how-to-populate-the-filestream-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty good how-to, and it includes VB and C# code: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Files-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx

If you need to do bulk loading, just toss a loop around the code and feed it the list of files in the directories.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net is not suited for a bulk loading tasks.

Since the files are already on your file system, a simple console app could do the task.

- Get all the files in your image directory
- Loop over them to read the bytes
- Insert the data to your db.

Code:

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"MY_PATH");
 foreach (var file in files)
 {
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    string strQuery = "insert into imageData(Name, Data) values (@Name,@Data)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = data;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```